# Cookie not being sent to the backend in a cross-subdomain setup with axios and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, cookies, axios, subdomain

I have a front-end application running on `app.mywebsite.com` and a backend API running on `api.mywebsite.com`. I'm trying to send a cookie from the front-end to the backend using axios, but the cookie is not being sent in the request. My setup is as follows:

I'm making a request using axios with withCredentials: true:

```
axios
  .get(authConfig.refreshTokenEndpoint, { withCredentials: true })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log("Got new access token", res.data);
    setAccessToken(res.data.access_token);
    if (requestNewUserInfo) {
      requestUpdatedUserInfo();
    }
  })
  .catch(() => handleLogout());
```

I have a CORS configuration that allows the front-end subdomain and credentials:

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfiguration {
    @Value("${navaship.webapp.url}")
    private String webAppUrl;

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/api/v*/auth/refresh-token")
                        .allowedOrigins(webAppUrl)
                        .allowedMethods("GET")
                        .allowCredentials(true);

                registry.addMapping("/api/v*/**")
                        .allowedOrigins(webAppUrl)
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The SameSite attribute is set to "None" for production, and both the front-end and backend applications are served over HTTPS:

```
private String getRefreshTokenCookie(String refreshToken) {
    boolean isProdProfile = profileHelper.isProdProfileActive();
    return ResponseCookie.from(REFRESH_TOKEN_COOKIE_KEY, refreshToken)
            .maxAge(refreshTokenExpirationMs / 1000)
            .httpOnly(true)
            .sameSite("None")
            .secure(isProdProfile)
            .path("/api/v1/auth/refresh-token")
            .build().toString();
}
```

Despite this setup, the cookie is not being sent to the backend. I have checked the browser console for error messages and warnings related to cookies or CORS but found nothing. I have also verified that the cookie is created with the correct attributes.

In the backend, when trying to access the cookie from the request, the headerRefreshToken variable is null:

```
@GetMapping("/refresh-token")
public ResponseEntity<RefreshTokenResponse> refreshToken(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    String headerRefreshToken = null;

    if (cookies != null) {
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
            if (REFRESH_TOKEN_COOKIE_KEY.equals(cookie.getName())) {
                headerRefreshToken = cookie.getValue();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this issue and ensure the cookie is sent from the front-end to the backend?